# can i speed up my following code in oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following code in my oracle database :

```
select filename, count(envelop), sum(execution_num)
from (
  select t.filename, s.envelop, count(s.envelop) as execution_num
  from tbl_document s, tbl_log t
  where t.exedoc = s.exedoc
    and s.status = 32
    
  group by t.filename, s.envelop
)
group by filename;
```

results:

```
Live_file_2121_1    247     285
Live_file_2121_2    7189    7257
Live_file_2121_3    7298    7935
Live_file_2121_4    3162    9527
Live_file_2121_5    2734    8100
Live_file_2121_6    5679    5745
Live_file_2121_7    6391    6537
Live_file_2121_8    9818    10093
Live_file_2121_9    4514    4656
```

But there is problem this query almost take one hour

any idea how i can speed up this query .

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please use modern `JOIN` syntax instead of the 1989 syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase the query without a subquery:

```
select l.filename,
       count(distinct d.envelop),
       count(*) as execution_num
from tbl_document d join
     tbl_log l
     on l.exedoc = d.exedoc
where d.status = 32
group by l.filename;
```

Then for this query, you probably want indexes on `tbl_document(status, exedoc, envelop)` and `tbl_log(exedoc, filename)`.

Comment: Take too much time also ? :(

Comment: @alimmenz . . . I assume Impaler's solution improved the performance.  Can you give an idea of what the performance differences are?

Comment: actually after execute it look like the same , also the first take long time :(

Answer (score 2):

The following indexes may improve the performance substantially:

```
create index ix1 on tbl_document (status, envelop);

create index ix2 on tbl_log (exedoc, filename);
```

Also, you should consider using modern join syntax, instead of the comma-separated syntax from 1989. You query can look like:

```
select filename, count(envelop), sum(execution_num)
from (
  select t.filename, s.envelop, count(s.envelop) as execution_num
  from tbl_document s
  join tbl_log t on t.exedoc = s.exedoc
  where s.status = 32
  group by t.filename, s.envelop
) x
group by filename;
```

Comment: Thanks so much ... actually this my old programmer app and i start to modify all the things , btw thank you so much ... u are big star, it is help a lot

Comment: @The Impaler, I would appreciate if you could help me understand what is the reason behind creating the indexes in short ? I mean I understand the part we need index on `tbl_document.status` or `tbl_log.exedoc` but I don't understand the why composite index and which part of the query needs these indexes ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Regarding the indexes, the engine needs to pick one table as the "driving" table and the other one as "secondary" in the join. Now which one is which one? Since there's a filtering predicate `s.status = 32`, then the engine will probably choose `tbl_document` as the driving table and that's the most important index: tbl_document (status, envelop). Then it'll need to access the secondary table using the predicate `t.exedoc = ...`; here the index tbl_log (exedoc, filename) comes to play to make this access as fast as possible. The extra columns make the indexes "covering indexes"

Comment: @The Impaler, Thank you vey much for the explanation. I was not aware of the term `"covering indexes"`.

Comment: Hi @TheImpaler i executed the code what you wrote it , but without index and also take long time :(

Comment: @alimmenz Yes, the indexes are necessary to improve performance.

Comment: @TheImpaler , iam just no expert like you , and please can you patient to me, it is mean i should execute the two index what u wrote and then start my query ?
another question :
is that will effect the database or add column or how ?

thanks in advance

Comment: @alimmenz Yes, you need to execute those two `CREATE INDEX` statements first; it can take some time depending on how big the table is; and they need to be created only once. Then you can run your query as many times you want and it should benefit from the new indexes. You ask: "Will there new indexes produce any side effect on the database?" Yes, modification operations such as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE will be [marginally] slower. Should be barely perceptible.